# Импорт Svg файлов в List<Sprite> через код Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Не импортируются svg-файлы(Textured Sprite) через код:

```
Resources.Load<Sprite>("camping");
```

Спрайты находятся в папке Assets/Resources/camping, но код их почему-то не видит, хотя при ручном импорте(т.е. перетаскиванием на public sprite) всё хорошо. Файлов очень большое количество и хотелось бы загрузить их всех разом в один List, но этот код тоже не работает:

```
pics.AddRange(Resources.FindObjectsOfTypeAll<Sprite>());
```

Прошу вашей помощи, господа.

Comment: [Вот ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56249697/unity-accessing-generated-svg-sprites-programmatically), оно?

Comment: @aepot, не, не это. способ (Sprite) Resources.Load("camping") не работает.

Comment: Мне кажется, там в ответах немного другое

Comment: @aepot у меня объекты находятся в папке и не загружены на сцену. на сцене есть только UI Image, на котором закреплён код с List<Sprite> в который нужно загрузить все спрайты(svg-файлы) из папки Resources, поэтому решение, которое вы отправили мне не подходит. У меня не проблема с тем, как присвоить спрайт объекту, у меня проблема с автоматической загрузкой спрайтов в лист.

Comment: Расширение файла не указано.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker, спасибо за совет. а где его указывать?

Comment: `Resources.Load<Sprite>("camping.svg")`

Comment: @RiotBr3aker, camping - это папка

Comment: А с чего вы решили, что `Resources.Load` загружает папку? В документации явно указано, что туда нужно передавать путь до файла.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для загрузки из папки нужно использовать [`Resources.LoadAll`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.LoadAll.html).

```
// массив
var arr = Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>("camping");

// список
var lst = new List<Sprite>(Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>("camping"));
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!

Comment: @ИгорьПетров если ответ вам помог, не забудьте поставить +1 помимо принятия ответа ;)